# Java String.replaceAll regex

Tags: java, regex, string

What is the regex to strip the MY-CORP\ part of na inputed string like MY-CORP\My.Name with the java `String.replaceAll` method so I can get only the My.Name part?

I tried

```
public static String stripDomain(String userWithDomain) {
    return userWithDomain.replaceAll("^.*\\", "");
}
```

but i got *Unexpected internal error near index 4 ^.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that the backslash has special meaning both in Java strings and in regexes. So you need four slashes in the Java source code, passing two to the regex parser to get one literal one in the regex:

```
return userWithDomain.replaceAll("^.*\\\\", "");
```